# Getting a syntax error saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'. What is that i am missing here

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

My Dynamic SQL generated the below code.

When i am trying to run it I am getting a syntax error saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'pivot'."

What is that i am missing here?

```sql
    SELECT month (Sale.[Date]) as Month, 
    [5],
    [10],
    [15],
    [20],
    [25],
    [30],
    [35],
    [40],
    [45],
    [60] 
    INTO ##TBL_TEMP 
    from Limit L 
    right join Store S 
      on L.Limit_Mins = S.Limit_Mins 
    join Sale Sa 
      on S.Store_Number=Sa.Store_number 
    join [Date] Dt 
      on Dt.[Date]=Sa.[Date] 
    join Product P 
      on Sa.PID=P.PID 
    left outer join Discount D 
      on Sa.PID=D.PID and Sa.[Date]=D.Discount_Date 
    group by month (Sale.[Date]),
        case  when S.Limit_Mins = L.Limit_Mins and S.Childcare_Flag=1 then S.Limit_Mins end  
    pivot (
        sum(case when S.Limit_Mins = L.Limit_Mins and S.Childcare_Flag=1 then
               case when D.PID =Sa.PID and D.Discount_Date=Sa.[Date] then
                   D.Discount_Price
               else
                   P.Retail_price
               end
               * Sa.Quantity
            else
               0
            end ),   
        sum(case when S.Childcare_Flag = 0 then
                case when D.PID =Sa.PID and D.Discount_Date=Sa.[Date] then
                    D.Discount_Price
                else
                    P.Retail_price
                end
                * Sa.Quantity
            else
                0
            end)  
    for
        case when S.Limit_Mins = L.Limit_Mins and S.Childcare_Flag=1 then
           S.Limit_Mins end 
    in ([5],[10],[15],[20],[25],[30],[35],[40],[45],[60])
) as Q
```

Comment: You really should format your query into something more readable with proper indenting, that's a mess for someone to wade through :)

Comment: I don't get it: was this generated dynamically, because there is nothing dynamic about it. Your syntax has a bunch of errors: you can only `PIVOT` on one column, and it must be on a single table or derived subquery/CTE, so you are going to have to put this into a subquery/CTE. I also question why the `for` is on a `case` expression that does not have an `else`, you may as well have put that in the `where`. Furthermore, the `right join` doesn't make sense for the same reason

Comment: your query syntax is wrong. You have `GROUP BY` in the middle. Please check with documentation on proper syntax for a `SELECT`  query

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , Thanks to a video from wiseowl tutorials on youtube